# Как изменить значение multiplier (в constraint) через код?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, iphone

Есть `TextView`, у которого есть `NSLayoutConstraint (textViewHeight)`, значение `multiplier` равняется `0.3`, при нажатии на этот `TextView` значение `multiplier` должно увеличиваться до `0.6`.

Пытаюсь написать `_textViewHeight.multiplier = 0.6`, но Xcode ругается, что поле `mutiplier` является `readonly` и его нельзя изменять.

На форумах советуют создать вторую `Constraint` с другим значением и переключаться между двумя `Constraint` с разными значениями. Но как это сделать?

Answer (score 1):

Да, `multiplier` является `read only property`, и его изменять нельзя, и для вас, действительно, подойдет решение использовать еще одни `constraints`. Вот для примера как вы можете это сделать:

```
NSLayoutConstraint *standardConstraint, *zoomedConstraint;
// ...
// switch between constraints
standardConstraint.active = NO;
zoomedConstraint.active = YES;
[self.view layoutIfNeeded]; // or using
```

Но а установить `constraint` вы можете так:

```
[self.view addConstraints:standardConstraint
        options:NSLayoutFormatDirectionLeadingToTrailing
                           metrics:nil
views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(_textView)]];
```